# Objective-C: How do I save results to a second view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am a noob and need some guidance. I haven't messed with programming in 7 years. 
In objective-C. How can I save results to a second view controller? 
Lets say root view controller is a calculator. After I get the result I want to be able to hit a save button and the data will be saved to the second view controller. The second view controller will list the results. I will want to be able to delete them with a swipe of my finger.

Comment: can you show me your code how you are transiting betweening view controller

Comment: Currently I don't have any code. I am basically finding examples and then building off of those.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

Create a property data in the 2nd View controller, and before pushing / displaying the view controller you set that property.

Comment: Viking: I do know how to use a search box. I have spent long enough looking and am hoping I can get help this way.

Comment: @user1988925 — and you found nothing? funny, my version of stackoverflow gives me 800+ results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bobjective-c%5D+pass+object+view+controller but sure it is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Do bellow steps :

First you import your second view controller header file to first one.
firstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "secondViewController.h"
```

In second view controller header create a property 
secondViewController.h

```
@property NSString *passingValue;
```

Create a instance of secondViewController

```
secondViewController *targetVC ;
targetVC.passingValue = newValue;
```

Now you `@synthesize passingValue, in secondViewController.m

Now you can get values to secondViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"Image Name : %@ ",passingValue);
   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: the use of `@synthesize` is not needed anymore. it will be done as default with an underscore prefixed ivar.